# QOOXDOO extend - Не наследуются static свойства

Tags: qooxdoo, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Возник вопрос интересный.
Есть флеймворк qooxdoo. При создании дочернего класса не наследуются statics свойства родителя. Что может быть не так ?

пример:

```
qx.Class.define('sdf.items.BaseItem', {
   extend: qx.core.Object,
   statics: {
      TEST: 1
   }
});

qx.Class.define('sdf.items.ChildItem', {
   extend: sdf.items.BaseItem
});

sdf.items.ChildItem.TEST //undefined
```

Может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался ?

P.S. Пробовал юзать Mixins и т.д. - проблема остается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.4/pages/core/oo_feature_summary.html

> Note Static members **aren't inherited**. For calling a superclass static method, use this.superclass, like in this example:

```
qx.Class.define('A', {
  statics: {
     f: function() {}
  }
});

qx.Class.define('B'), {
  extend: A,
  members: {
     e: function() {
        this.superclass.self(arguments).f();
     }
  }
});
```

> Static functions can access other static functions directly through the this keyword.

Говоря по русски static не наследуется (остается в базовом классе), чтобы получить доступ к static надо использовать доступ до родительского класса через свойство `superclass`

```
qx.Class.define('sdf.items.BaseItem', {
   extend: qx.core.Object,
   statics: {
      TEST: 1
   }
});

qx.Class.define('sdf.items.ChildItem', {
   extend: sdf.items.BaseItem
});

console.log(sdf.items.ChildItem.superclass.TEST); //1
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ситуация ясна.